# Find the match between Binary and SVN

Tags: svn, war

I was wondering if someone can help me with a solution.
There is a compiled binary code for a server that is running and working fine, but I am not sure whether the code in SVN matches the binary? 
Please help me to find whether both matches.

Thanks
Marshal

Answer (score 0):

1. Try to compare the md5 of both files
2. If you have use the svn to deploy - run `svn st` on server